# Como alterar dados duplicados em um dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

Estou tentando automatizar um processo que faço manualmente no excel.
Que é extrair a base de funcionários da empresa do excel, selecionar algumas colunas específicas (pois o arquivo é muito grande), remover determinado nivel de hierarquia e filtrar algumas empresas. até aqui foi. se quiserem dar alguma sugestão para melhor será muito bem vinda. porem na coluna nome, tem alguns nomes duplicados são pessoas realmente diferentes. É preciso manter duplicado. minha dúvida é quando faço no excel eu coloco "." no final de cada nome para diferenciar, consigo fazer isso pelo python? estou usando o googlecolab.

obs: quando rodo apresenta 2 erros

1. WARNING *** file size (7827463) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
2. /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:6: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
   é normal?

```
view = pd.read_excel ("/content/View.xls")
filtro = view['Emp'] < 4
filtro2 = view['Hierarquia Cargo'] > 3
view1 = view[filtro]
view5 = view1[filtro2]
bd = view5 [['Nome', 'Emp', 'EST', 'Matr', 'Nome Estabelecimento', 'Descr Unid Lotacao', 'Descr CC', 'Desc Afast']]
bd = bd.sort_values (by='Nome', ascending=True)
display (bd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode renomear os duplicados sim. Veja abaixo

### Criando DataFrame teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"frutas": ["banana", "goiaba", "laranja", "banana", "uva", "laranja", "banana"]})

>>> df
    frutas
0   banana
1   goiaba
2  laranja
3   banana
4      uva
5  laranja
6   banana
```

### Renomeando duplicados

```
>>> df["frutas"] = df.frutas.where(~df.frutas.duplicated(), df.frutas + '.')

>>> df
     frutas
0    banana
1    goiaba
2   laranja
3   banana.
4       uva
5  laranja.
6   banana.
```

Perceba que existem uma `banana` e duas `banana.`... Isso exemplifica o caso de você possuir várias pessoas com o mesmo nome.

### Rodando mais uma vez para tirar o segundo caso de `banana.`

```
>>> df["frutas"] = df.frutas.where(~df.frutas.duplicated(), df.frutas + '.')

>>> df
     frutas
0    banana
1    goiaba
2   laranja
3   banana.
4       uva
5  laranja.
6  banana..
```